# comparing hashed values from sql table

Tags: mysql, select, md5

i have an md5 hash i need to compare to values in a mysql table.

stored in the table for somefield is somevalue.
the string being passed is the md5 of somevalue.

is there a mysql command

```
select * from table
where md5 value of somefiled = md5string
```

Comment: Curious... Why is the data being passed in hashed form?  I ask because it sounds like a potential indicator that the data may need to be _stored_ in hashed form as well.  This would make the comparison trivial, of course.  But if we're talking about something that _should_ be encrypted, then it probably _should_ be encrypted both in transit and at rest.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE md5(somefield)='16t1gu6g216g21g...'
```

Comment: Well, `somefield` was meant to be replaced by the actual name of your column

Comment: do have any idea how I would achieve this comparison